# scaling multi-tenant elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a noob elasticsearch architecure question which goes like this :

### state

- I am running a 5.x version of elasticsearch
- I am in a multi tenant elasticsearch environment.
- I have a single elasticsearch cluster made up of X nodes.
- Each tenant is assigned a single index.
- Elasticsearch is proxied via an API. The consumers of data stored in elasticsearch don't talk to it directly. The API determines the tenant and responds to queries

> As  the number of tenants increase, having a single cluster seems difficult to maintain (atleast in my head)

### what have i tried ? (or could try)

- Option A : add more nodes to the same cluster
- Option B : setup multiple clusters and have the API aware of the clusters. The clients of the service will still be agnostic of the underlying cluster(s).

### question

I want to understand what metrics I should be looking at to make a decision of having multiple clusters vs adding more nodes to the same cluster? and when to cut over

Comment: how many indices do you have in you cluster? how many shards per indices and how many docs per indices do you have?